# Typescript map iteration gives error map.keys is not a function in cloud function

Tags: typescript, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, google-cloud-functions

typescript code in firebase cloud function gives an error

```
TypeError: variations.keys is not a function
```

code snippet causes error given below

```
 const currentDoc = await transaction.get(ref)
 if (currentDoc !== undefined) {        
 const variations = currentDoc.get('variation') as Map<string,any>
 for (const i of variations.keys()) {
 }
```

firebase console shows this error

```
TypeError: variations.keys is not a function
at Object.<anonymous> (/user_code/lib/index.js:54:52)
at next (native)
at fulfilled (/user_code/lib/index.js:4:58)
at process._tickDomainCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:135:7)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This seems to be a misunderstanding of TypeScript's [type assertions](https://basarat.gitbooks.io/typescript/docs/types/type-assertion.html). Note that we aren't calling them "type casts", since it's not a type cast in a well-known sense.

The main point you should know here is that *type assertions are compiled into nothing*. Check your code in [TypeScript playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/#src=const%20currentDoc%20%3D%20await%20transaction.get(ref)%0D%0Aif%20(currentDoc%20!%3D%3D%20undefined)%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20const%20variations%20%3D%20currentDoc.get('variation')%20as%20Map%3Cstring%2C%20any%3E%0D%0A%20%20%20%20for%20(const%20i%20of%20variations.keys())%20%7B%0D%0A%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%7D%0D%0A%7D) - it throws a lot of compile errors, obviously, since it's not an [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve), but it's good enough to see that there is no notion of `Map` on the right part of the screen. So, you get the pure object, try to use it as a `Map`, and, obviously, it is an error.

What are the type assertions used for? They are used, if you know preemptively that *at runtime* the type will be different from the one declared in compile-time. In this case, if you have really received a `Map` from `currentDoc.get`, but TypeScript insisted on the possibility of plain object, you can just say "treat this as `Map`, I know what I'm doing". Of course, in this case all the validations fall on yourself.

Now, what to do here? I don't know the Firebase API, so I can't make any concrete advice, but a general direction might be the following:

1) Just use the plain old JavaScript object. You have [Object.keys()](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/keys), [for..of loop](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for...of), and so on.

2) Explicitly convert this object into the `Map`. The simplest way (although requiring the ES2017 support) is the following one-liner: `const variations = new Map(Object.entries(currentDoc.get('variation')));`

Answer (score 1):

You can't just cast the result of `get()` to a Map.  If you have a DocumentSnapshot object, and the document contains an object type field, it will show up in the snapshot as a plain old JavaScript object.

Comment: currrentDoc is a document snapshot. And i am using async and await. currrentDoc consist of  a nested object named variation. it,s field names are dynamic. So i am trying to cast variation object to map and using map.keys() for field names. But it gives error TypeError: variations.keys is not a function

Comment: You still can't just cast to a Map.  If you have a snapshot in hand, and that snapshot has on object field, it will just be a regular javascript object with properties that match the properties of the object field.